# Clear not reset p:autocomplete boxes

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have to clear (show the assigned watermark again) after a p:autocomplete selectedValue attribute has been nulled.

I tried to set (after the selectedValue was set to null) to set the value to an empty string, without any positive effect.

In short: I want to set the watermark value again as placeholder text in the p:autocomplete control.

Thanks for help!

**My *.xhtml**

```
<h:form>
        <p:watermark for="selectmyvalue" value="Select value"/>
        <p:autoComplete id="selectmyvalue"
                        dropdown="true"
                        var="myval"
                        value="#{myValBean.Name}"
                        completeMethod="..."
                        itemLabel="#{myval.name}"
                        itemValue="#{myval}"
                        converter="#{myvalConverter}"">

            <p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="..."/>
        </p:autoComplete>
</h:form>
```

**My java snippet**

```
public void onSomething()
{
    myValBean.value = null;
}
```

Comment: Hi. You can try to force selection using `forceSelection="true"` attribute. It's not exactily what you want but my help and be simple.

Comment: Hi, that's not the way I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since JSF 2.2, the p:autocomplete has the attribute '*placeholder*' which works as expected.
Thanks everyone!